# Ruby/Rails: Keeping Namespaced Nested Resources DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a small Ruby/Rails app that has an `admin` namespace. When an admin logs in, they are redirected to a small dashboard that displays company logos (this app is a Service Request Claim app). An admin can then click on a logo to then see that company's Service Requests.

My Routes:

```
  resources :customers
  resources :service_requests do
    resources :notes
  end

  namespace :admin do
    get '', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'
    resources :companies do
      resources :service_requests
    end
  end
```

As it is now, there would be 2 service requests controllers (one for /admin and one for regular users). Users `belong_to` a company and will see Service Requests for the company they belong to.

Is it ok to have 2 service request controllers?

**EDIT**

Here is my output from `rake routes`

```
                  service_requests GET    /service_requests(.:format)                                      service_requests#index
                                   POST   /service_requests(.:format)                                      service_requests#create
               new_service_request GET    /service_requests/new(.:format)                                  service_requests#new
              edit_service_request GET    /service_requests/:id/edit(.:format)                             service_requests#edit
                   service_request GET    /service_requests/:id(.:format)                                  service_requests#show
                                   PATCH  /service_requests/:id(.:format)                                  service_requests#update
                                   PUT    /service_requests/:id(.:format)                                  service_requests#update
                                   DELETE /service_requests/:id(.:format)                                  service_requests#destroy
                             admin GET    /admin(.:format)                                                 admin/dashboard#index
                 admin_set_company GET    /admin/set_company(.:format)                                     admin/dashboard#set_company
    admin_company_service_requests GET    /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests(.:format)          admin/service_requests#index
                                   POST   /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests(.:format)          admin/service_requests#create
 new_admin_company_service_request GET    /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests/new(.:format)      admin/service_requests#new
edit_admin_company_service_request GET    /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests/:id/edit(.:format) admin/service_requests#edit
     admin_company_service_request GET    /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests/:id(.:format)      admin/service_requests#show
                                   PATCH  /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests/:id(.:format)      admin/service_requests#update
                                   PUT    /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests/:id(.:format)      admin/service_requests#update
                                   DELETE /admin/companies/:company_id/service_requests/:id(.:format)      admin/service_requests#destroy
```

Comment: You don't have two controllers, you have two routes mapping to the same controller and this is absolutely fine.

Comment: According to the `rake routes` the mapping is to 2 different controllers... one in the normal namespace and one in the `/admin` namespace

Comment: You can make it to route to the same controller by adding `module: false` to your `namespace` call.

Comment: that's awesome! Had no idea you could do that! Thanks!

Comment: If you are thinking show a different result to admin and regular users, i think that is a right solution keep two controllers (one for admin user and other for regular user). But if the information its the same, and the presentation too...not have sence use two different controller, you can play with routes to use only one controller.

Comment: @kikicarbonell - yeah the presentation and information is exactly the same

Comment: @dennismonsewicz then you can play with routes to use only one controller...if you need more explanation tell me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking show a different result to admin and regular users, i think that is a right solution keep two controllers (one for admin user and other for regular user). But if the information its the same, and the presentation too...not have sence use two different controller, you can play with routes to use only one controller.